# Apache Calcite - registering UDFs for use in RelBuilder

Tags: java, user-defined-functions, apache-calcite

The OOTB sample udf junits (UdfTest.java) make use of a dummy jdbc schema and do not show the usage of RelBuilder api.

I am working on registering a simple UDF that returns the length of the input string. I have created the SqlFunction and registered the same in the SqlStdOperatorTable -

```
SqlFunction length = new SqlFunction("STRLEN",
                SqlKind.OTHER_FUNCTION,
                ReturnTypes.INTEGER,
                null,
                OperandTypes.STRING,
                SqlFunctionCategory.USER_DEFINED_FUNCTION);

SqlStdOperatorTable sqlStdOperatorTable = SqlStdOperatorTable.instance();
sqlStdOperatorTable.register(length);
```

And used this for creating the FrameworkConfig -

```
FrameworkConfig frameworkConfig = Frameworks.newConfigBuilder()
                .parserConfig(SqlParser.Config.DEFAULT)
                .defaultSchema(connection.getRootSchema().getSubSchema("SYSTEM"))
                .programs(Programs.sequence(Programs.ofRules(Programs.RULE_SET), Programs.CALC_PROGRAM))
                .operatorTable(sqlStdOperatorTable)
                .build();
```

Now I can use the predefined sql functions like `substr`, defined in class SqlStringLengthFunction, with following piece-

```
RelNode udfRelNode = builder
                .scan("EMP")
                .project(builder.call(new SqlStringLengthFunction(),builder.literal("SampleString"), builder.literal(3))
                .build();

PreparedStatement statement = RelRunners.run(udfRelNode);
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

but when I try with the above function 'length' in builder.call, it throws exception -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot translate call STRLEN($t3)
```

The builder fetches the implementation of these functions from a private map in `RexImpTable` class.
No public/protected apis are exposed in this class for adding values to this map.

Can you please guide how to register any UDF with Calcite and use the same with RelBuilder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment on calcite jira for my question [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-3394) answers the question with one approach-

> This is because SqlStdOperatorTable.instance() did some initialization work for the registered functions. So an invoke of #register after it would not work as expected. The correct way is to use ListSqlOperatorTable and chained it with the StdSqlOperatorTable with ChainedSqlOperatorTable, the presudo code may like this:

```
ListSqlOperatorTable listOpTable = new ListSqlOperatorTable();
listOpTable.add(my_udf);
ChainedSqlOperatorTable chainedOpTable = ChainedSqlOperatorTable.of(listOpTable, SqlStdOperatorTable.instance());
// then use this chainedOpTable

// If you want to use a special dialect operators, you can code like this
SqlOperatorTable optable = SqlLibraryOperatorTableFactory.INSTANCE
  .getOperatorTable(SqlLibrary.STANDARD, SqlLibrary.POSTGRESQL);
```

I resolved my issue with following approach -

```
// methods containing the udf logic 
public static class MyUdf1 {
        public Integer eval(String a) {
            return a.length();
        }
    }


@Test
    public void test1() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        CalciteConnection connection = MyTests.getCalciteConnection();

        final String functionName = "STR_LEN";
        final ScalarFunction udfLengthFunction = ScalarFunctionImpl.create(Types.lookupMethod(MyUdf1.class, "eval", String.class));
        connection.getRootSchema().getSubSchema("SYSTEM").add(functionName, udfLengthFunction);

        FrameworkConfig frameworkConfig = Frameworks.newConfigBuilder()
                .parserConfig(SqlParser.Config.DEFAULT)
                .defaultSchema(connection.getRootSchema().getSubSchema("SYSTEM"))
                .programs(Programs.sequence(Programs.ofRules(Programs.RULE_SET), Programs.CALC_PROGRAM))
                .build();

        SqlIdentifier udfLengthIdentifier = new SqlIdentifier(Collections.singletonList(functionName), null, SqlParserPos.ZERO, null);
        final SqlOperator strLenOperator = new SqlUserDefinedFunction(udfLengthIdentifier, ReturnTypes.INTEGER, null, OperandTypes.STRING, null, udfLengthFunction);

        final RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(frameworkConfig);
        RelNode udfRelNode = builder
                .scan("EMP")
                .project(builder.call(strLenOperator, builder.literal("SampleString")))
                .build();

        ResultSet set = RelRunners.run(udfRelNode).executeQuery();
        set.next();
        System.out.println(set.getString(1));
    }
```