# How to register UDF in Apache Calcite so it will be push down while executing RelNode

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-calcite

I've registered my custom UDF like described here [Apache Calcite - registering UDFs for use in RelBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268828/apache-calcite-registering-udfs-for-use-in-relbuilder):

```java
    public static class ConvertTimestampToString {

        public final static String NAME = "format_datetime";
        private static final Map<String, DateTimeFormatter> FORMATTERS = new WeakHashMap<>();

        public final static ScalarFunction FUNCTION = ScalarFunctionImpl.create(
                Types.lookupMethod(
                        ConvertTimestampToString.class,
                        "eval",
                        Timestamp.class,
                        String.class));

        public final static SqlIdentifier IDENTIFIER = new SqlIdentifier(
                Collections.singletonList(NAME),
                null,
                SqlParserPos.ZERO,
                null);

        public final static SqlOperator SQL_OPERATOR = new SqlUserDefinedFunction(
                IDENTIFIER,
                ReturnTypes.VARCHAR_2000,
                null,
                OperandTypes.family(SqlTypeFamily.TIMESTAMP, SqlTypeFamily.STRING),
                null,
                FUNCTION);

        public String eval(Timestamp source, String format) {
            try {
                var formatter = FORMATTERS
                        .computeIfAbsent(format, f -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(f));
                return source.toLocalDateTime().format(formatter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result if fine, except one thing - it doesn't push down the call to the source.

```java
            RelNode node = builder
                    .scan(source)
                    .filter(builder.isNotNull(builder.field("valid_to_dttm")))
                    .project(builder.call(
                            TrinoSqlOperatorTable.ConvertTimestampToString.SQL_OPERATOR,
                            builder.field("valid_to_dttm"),
                            builder.literal("YYYY/MM")))
                    .limit(0, 10)
                    .build();
// ...
        try (PreparedStatement st = relRunner.prepareStatement(node);
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
            QueryLogsUtil.logTrinoSqlQuery(rs);
            printResultSet(rs);
        }
```

Finally it generates following request:

```
LogicalSort(fetch=[10])
  LogicalProject(resolution_dttm=[format_datetime($0, _UTF-16'MM/YYYY':CHAR(7) CHARACTER SET "UTF-16")])
    LogicalFilter(condition=[IS NOT NULL($0)])
      JdbcTableScan(table=[[trino, m1-gp-tst-ext, hercule_test, jira_issue]])

SELECT *
FROM "m1-gp-tst-ext"."hercule_test"."jira_issue"
WHERE "resolution_dttm" IS NOT NULL
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

It means calling of `format_datetime` was not propagated to the source and was calculated in the calcite. What should I fix so the request will look like `SELECT format_datetime(valid_to_dttm, 'YYYY/MM') FROM ...`?

Example will be perfect help!

Comment: For this to work, you have to first need to have the UDF available in the source database. It can't be pushed down if your database is unable to execute the UDF itself. See this related discussion on the mailing list https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@calcite.apache.org/msg03131.html

Comment: Lets assume format_datetime is available. What should I do to make it works as I want?